# Friend Function name undefined

Tags: c++, friend

I tried to pass a friend function name `comp` to `set_intersection`, compiled in Visual Studio 2019 with a compilation error: *E0020    identifier "comp" is undefined*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Test {
    friend bool comp(const Test& A, const Test& B) { return A.a < B.a; }
public: 
    int a{ 10 };
};

int main() {
    vector<Test> v1{ Test{} };
    vector<Test> v2{ Test{} };
    vector<Test> rs;

    set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(rs), comp);
}
```

However, if I changed `comp` to `operator<`, it works fine with `set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(rs));`. Why `comp` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comp` is not visible for lookup here. For [friend declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend),

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within a class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided

(Note that ADL only works for function-call expressions, i.e. `comp(...);`.)

You need to provide a declaration at the global namespace.

```
bool comp(const Test& A, const Test& B);
class Test {
    friend bool comp(const Test& A, const Test& B) { return A.a < B.a; }
public: 
    int a{ 10 };
};

int main() {
    vector<Test> v1{ Test{} };
    vector<Test> v2{ Test{} };
    vector<Test> rs;

    set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(rs), comp);
}
```

Comment: Even without a declaration at the global namespace, `comp(v1[0], v2[0]);` still works, I think it's made possible by ADL, right? But why ADL doesn't work within the `set_intersection` function call?

Comment: @Neymar87 ADL only works for function-call expressions, i.e. `comp(...);`.

Comment: But why operator< works smoothly? Isn't it also a friend function?

Comment: @Neymar87 It'll be called by `set_intersection`, ADL takes effect. If you just refer to it as `operator<`, it can't be found either.

Comment: @Neymar87 The problem is the usage of name `comp` in `set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(rs), comp);`, the name `comp` can't be found. If you use `operator<` instead like `set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(rs), operator<);`, it won't work either.